# Error when using data-member of a class inside a friend function defined in another class

Tags: c++, g++, forward-declaration, friend-function

So, here I have two classes, one has the friend function definition and the other a private data member. I want to access the private data member with the friend member function but it gives me an error in the part: obj->x inside the friend member function, it says that the 'x' data member is declared after the friend function, and I can't use it, but I already put the forward declaration, so I am lost.

Here the code:

```
class cl2; // Forward declaration

class cl1 {
   int y;
   public:
   cl1(int num){ y = num; }
   void setx(cl2 *obj, int num) { obj->x = num; } // friend function definition, here is the error.
};

class cl2 {
   int x;
   public:
   cl2(int num){ x = num; }
   friend void cl1::setx(cl2 *obj, int num);
   int getx() { return x; }
};

int main() {

   cl2 objcl2(2);
   cl1 objcl1(1);
   objcl1.setx(&objcl2, 20);

   cout << objcl2.getx() << "\n\n";


   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

I tried to declare cl2 class before cl1.
I changed the way of accessing 'x'. I used a reference (&) and a pointer (*).

Comment: You can not access details about a class's definition before you have defined it.

Comment: Your code has a circular dependency issue. The cl1 class needs the full definition of cl2 to access its private member x, and at the same time, cl2 needs the full definition of cl1 to declare the friend function.

Comment: Put definition of `cl1::setx` after: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7M6cTbc4)